# How do I check for major diagonal conflicts in an array of arrays using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

For example, say I have this array of arrays:

```
Board = [
[ 0, 0, 0, 1],
[ 1, 0, 0, 1],
[ 0, 1, 0, 0]
[ 0, 0, 1, 0]
]
```

And now I want to check for main diagonal conflicts, such that no major diagonal contains more than one 1.  I've experimented with a variety of loops, but can't seem to clinch the right code.

Comment: Can you post the code that you've tried, along with outputs so we can see what your first attempts have been?

Comment: Can be done with one for loop.

Answer (score 0):

done with a single for loop

```
function testForCollision (Board) {
    // assuming square array
    var leftToRightFound = false,
        rightToLeftFound = false;
    for (var i = 0, j = Board.length-1; i < Board.length; i++, j--)
        if (Board[i][i] == 1) {
            if (leftToRightFound)
                return false;
            else
                leftToRight = true;
        }
        if (Board[i][j] == 1) {
            if (rightToLeftFound)
                return false;
            else
                rightToLeft = true;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```